# How dangerous would it be to start a jet engine with coins inside?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-failure

With the [multiple](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/flight-grounded-china-coin-engine-lucky-air-a8012666.html) [stories](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/elderly-woman-coins-jet-engine-chinese-good-luck-shanghai-guangzhou-china-southern-airlines-a7810721.html) in the news of people throwing coins into a jet engine for good luck, I couldn't help but wonder how dangerous it would be if the act went unnoticed and the crew started up the engine with the coins inside. Would the engine be damaged? Would the damage be noticed before the plane throttled up for takeoff or left the ground? I'm sure the answer is, to some extent, "it depends", but what's a worst case?

Comment: this question should be a duplicate of "how dangerous if rock sucked in"

Comment: I guess it works - it was "lucky" that other people noticed before the engines were fired up, thus eliminating potential for damage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you say "it depends". Modern jet engine front turbines are designed to reject foreign object debris outside the core, which is where the damage would really matter. Jets suck up hard foreign object debris like pebbles often enough and it will ding things a but but hardly cause catastrophic damage. I'm sure coin throwing *has* gone unnoticed, and it made no difference in the end.

Really, it's not a big risk for the most part, modern high-bypass turbofans have a large bypass duct, when coins are thrown into an engine which is not running they will drop to the bottom of the bypass duct and get blown harmlessly out the back when it's started. However, there's just enough risk that a coin could find its way into the compressors and cause enough damage to need expensive repairs, and that is why they will take the airplane out of service.

Of course it depends on the coin, if you threw this bad boy in it would be a different story:
[image: World's largest coin]

Comment: Well, if tossing something like *that* in went unnoticed, I'd be more worried about the competence of the crew than the reliability of the engine. Seriously, though, I imagine with a (regular-sized) coin, it would get pushed out of the engine quite quickly one way or the other, right?

Comment: If someone tosses a coin in the engine while it is stopped it will almost certainly get blown harmlessly through the bypass duct when the engine starts up. If the engine is running it will still probably go through the bypass.

Comment: Is it possible to aim for the core / compressors? : )

Comment: A thrown coin going in an arc @AnandS, it would be tough. I imagine it's within the realm of possibility.